# Binding Datagrid to ObservableCollection<T> in SIlverlight

Tags: c#, data-binding, silverlight-5.0

I am struggling to bind a DataGrid to an ObservableCollection in SIlverlight.

My very simple code is below. It currently shows a blank DataGrid. I have gone through tutorials etc and I am sure I am missing something very very basic.

Main Page XAML

```
<UserControl xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"  x:Class="Tower.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <sdk:DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" IsReadOnly="True" ColumnWidth="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tests, Mode=OneWay}" AllowDrop="True" />
</Grid>
```

Main Page Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;

        Tests = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
        Tests.Add(new Test() { Label = "Test1" });
        Tests.Add(new Test() { Label = "Test2" });
        Tests.Add(new Test() { Label = "Test3" });
        Tests.Add(new Test() { Label = "Test4" });
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
public class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 

    private String _Label;

    public String Label
    {
        get
        {
            return _Label;
        }
        set
        {
            _Label = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Label"));
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code -

- `You can only bind with property` and not with fields. so make `Test` property first.
- Second, you need to set the `DataContext to self for` binding to work.

  ```
  public partial class MainPage : UserControl
  {
     public ObservableCollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }

     public MainPage()
     {
         InitializeComponent();

         DataContext = this;

         Tests = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
         Tests.Add(new Test() { Label = "Test1" });
         Tests.Add(new Test() { Label = "Test2" });
         Tests.Add(new Test() { Label = "Test3" });
         Tests.Add(new Test() { Label = "Test4" });
     }
  }
  ```

**XAML -**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <sdk:DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" IsReadOnly="True" ColumnWidth="120"
              ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Tests,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                 AncestorType= UserControl}}" AllowDrop="True" />
</Grid>
```

Notice propertyName - It should be `Tests` and not `tests`. This is just a side-note, follow the naming conventions of Microsoft. Property name's first letter should be uppercase always.

Comment: Thank you! Still struggling after those changes however.

Comment: Have you updated the property name in xaml to `Tests` instead of `tests`?

Comment: It worked with:

ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Tests}"

So the problem seems to be omission of "DataContext."

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

- For binding to work Tests has to be a public property. (I was surprised to see that the property needed to be public but could not get it to work without)
- For referenceing the property in the binding you must either
- Set the datacontext like RV suggested
  Or reference like this:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=Tests}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Maybe the public requirement is not so strange after all, we are referencing an instance of another class. (Internal did not work either)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget :
**PUBLIC** ObservableCollection tests {get; private set}

Comment: Why public? Are you think that the class has not access to its private members?

Comment: Sorry ... I was thinking with viewmodels ...

Try to init your observablecollection before setting the datacontext.

Comment: Funnily enough I have upgraded the code above to work with MVVM now. It works a treat.